# ElasticSearch Match all only matching exact result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query like this on ElasticSearch

```
'query': {
    'bool': {
        'must': {
            'match': {
                '_all': 'Lampad'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not matching my document that has a name 'Lâmpada'

Its mapping is:

```
'name': {
  'type': 'multi_field',
  'fields': {
    'name': {
      'type': string
      'analyzer': indexAnalyzer
      'boost': 5.0
    }
    'raw': {
      'index': 'analyzed'
      'type': 'string'
      'analyzer': 'lowerAnalyzer'
    }
  }
```

Analyser:

```
 indexAnalyzer:
    type: custom
    tokenizer: standard
    filter: [standard, lowercase, asciifolding, ptStopWords]
 lowerAnalyzer:
    type: custom
    tokenizer: keyword
    filter: [lowercase, asciifolding]
```